# How to display Date-picker in IONIC 2?

Tags: ionic-framework, datepicker, ionic2

I wanted to display the DatePicker as soon as page loads.

```
<DatePicker
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/datePicker"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
        android:headerBackground="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        />
```

I used Android studio and wrote above code to get the output as in the below image.
[image: Expected Output in ionic]

I wanted to implement the same thing using ionic 2 and wrote below code to get the datepicker.

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core';
import {DatePicker} from 'ionic-native';
import {Calendar} from 'ionic-native';
import {Platform} from 'ionic-angular';

@Component({
  templateUrl: 'build/pages/hello-ionic/hello-ionic.html'
})
export class HelloIonicPage {



constructor(platform: Platform) {
    platform.ready().then(() => {
      let options = {
        date: new Date(),
        mode: 'date'
      }

  DatePicker.show(options).then(
    date => {
      alert('Selected date: ' + date);
    },
    error => {
      alert('Error: ' + error);
    }
  );
});


}
}
```

And im getting the DatePicker as in below image.
[image: Ionic DatePicker]

Now my question is how to get the same DatePicker as in the First image?

Comment: Sorry.I couldn't reduce the image size

Comment: can you please provide a plunker for the app that your doing just the calender part would help

Answer (score 0):

You are using DataPicker from Ionic-Native. You can research more about Ionic-Native but the brief idea is that it wraps all the different cordova plugins a user would need to make it easier.

For DataPicker, if you look into the source code, it is using the plugin from cordova-plugin-datapicker. (https://github.com/VitaliiBlagodir/cordova-plugin-datepicker)

Under the README, there are a bunch of options that you can select when initializing your DataPicker. The plugin only caters to defined android themes:

```
androidTheme - Android
Choose the theme of the picker
Type: Int
Values: THEME_TRADITIONAL | THEME_HOLO_DARK | THEME_HOLO_LIGHT | THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK | THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT
Default: THEME_TRADITIONAL
```

For more details about themes, you can check out this issue that was open at the DatePicker plugin. (https://github.com/VitaliiBlagodir/cordova-plugin-datepicker/issues/180) As all these themes are based on Android API, I have not yet seen any suggestions on how to manually change the colors. It would be good to post your question at the plugin page.

Comment: Its almost close what i'm looking for.But it displays as popup. Is there any way to get it on the page instead of popup?

Comment: What about using Calendar from Ionic-Native instead of DatePicker?

Comment: It is navigating the user from current application to calendar application.

Comment: If you are looking for a calendar, then DatePicker would not the correct choice as it is purely for selecting a date and time. If i'm correct, development for calendar UI in Ionic 2 is still not yet done and thus not supported. You can take a look at this posting and see the reply from Ionic team. (https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/calender-component/53782/3) There may be other ways to work around though but I'm not sure either.